# FATAL Exception Main android

Tags: android, exception, program-entry-point

I am getting FATAL Exception main error.Any help?

Here is the code:

> private void copyStream(String assetFilename, String outFileName )
>   throws IOException
>       {
>
> ```
>       Process mSuProcess;
>       mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
>       ContextWrapper myContext = null;
>                   InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(assetFilename);
>
>       OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
>
>       //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
>       byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
>       int length;
>       while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
>           myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
>       }
>
>       //Close the streams
>       myOutput.flush();
>       myOutput.close();
>       myInput.close();
>
>   }
>
>
> public void copyon(View view) throws IOException
> {
>   copyStream("floaton.xml","/system/etc/excluded-input-devices.xml"); 
>
> }
>
> public void copyoff(View view) throws IOException
> {
>  copyStream("floatoff.xml","/system/etc/excluded-input-devices.xml");
>
> }
> ```

And logcat

> 09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Could not execute method of the activity 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
>   09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-16 19:52:26.654:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(294):at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
>   09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):    ... 11 more 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294): Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   Broken pipe 09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294): at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.write(Native Method)
>   09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294): at
>   dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:171)
>   09-16 19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:300) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:256) 09-16
>   19:52:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(294):at
>   java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:167)

Comment: I am facing same issue.. but if i change "su" to "sh"
then it works (at least don't raise broken pipe exception)

Answer (score 0):

The base of the exception appears to be coming from "FileOutputStream.write", have you added the write permissions to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This Permission in your mainfest.I hope its work for you & u should initialize this object.In Your code you give the context value null thats why it is not working.

/** Required Some Intilization instead of null

ContextWrapper myContext = null;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: /** Required Some Intilization instead of null
ContextWrapper myContext = null;

Comment: Instead of ContextWrapper myContext = null ,I made private ContextWrapper myContext;And even removed myContext,still no solution.

Comment: intialze your ContextWrapper like ContextWrapper myContext=new ContextWrapper();

Answer (score 0):

Please using AsyncTask or Thread.
If you wrote your own method, you can use like this:

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            copyStream();
        }
    }
);
```

OR using **AsyncTask**

Answer (score 0):

By default you don't have write permission on `/system/etc`, (unless you did some hack on your device). change it to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folderName/excluded-input-devices.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling onClick method inside the thread. This is not possible as views are in main thread they can't be accessed from any other thread.